# multiselect dropdown with dependent listbox

Tags: xml, vba

I am trying to create a drop down that is dependent on the selections made of another drop down menu that is multi-select.

E.g. In first drop-down the person has the choice of A, B, C, D, E or F  so if the person selects let's say A and E. And i want another drop down to appear with A1, A2, A3, E1, E2 and E3. If Suppose i select A, B and C  then the another listbox or dropdown must show the list
A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, C1, C2 and C3.  (these aren't the real values but hopefully this illustrates the idea).

I have the first field working fine for multi-select (used vba), and the second column will work using data validation indirect as long as only 1 entry is selected by the user (they choose only 1 of A, B, C, D,E or F), but as soon as they choose more than 1 then indirect no longer works.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I haven't been able to find an answer anywhere :(?

Comment: Please, edit your question and post the code you have. And what you tried by your own, if the case... How did you try `Indirect` for accomplishing what you need?

Comment: What do you mean by "drop down menu that is multi-select." Do you speak about a menu item or about a cell list validation? Anyhow, there is not possible to multi select in the way you do it in a list box. Do you want meaning that the validation cell will firstly keep the first validation issue, next time the first plus the second and so on? If you do not share your code, I am afraid that we cannot help you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you do not answer my clarification answer, please try the next approach. It assumes that 'multiselecting' means showing the existing cell value, plus the next selected one. The validated cell will be "G1" on the active sheet:

1. Create a validation to a cell, able to show "A, B, C, D, E". Copy the next code in a standard module, or in the sheet module, where the cell exists:

```
Sub CreateValidation()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range
 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 Set rng = sh.Range("G1")
 
 With rng.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                   Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="A,B,C,D,E"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
 End With
End Sub
```

2. In the module sheet where you want to control the validation as you asked in your question, at least as I understood it, copy the next code, please. To reach the sheet module, you may right click on the sheet name and choose `View Code`:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 Dim rngDV As Range, oldVal As String, newVal As String

 If Target.count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler
 If Target.value = "" Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
     Target.Offset(0, -1).value = ""
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
 End If
On Error Resume Next
 Set rngDV = cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
 On Error GoTo exitHandler

 If rngDV Is Nothing Then GoTo exitHandler

 If Not Intersect(Target, rngDV) Is Nothing Then
   Application.EnableEvents = False
   newVal = Target.value: Application.Undo
   oldVal = Target.value: Target.value = newVal
  
   If Target.Column = 7 Then
    If oldVal <> "" Then
      If newVal <> "" Then
         Target.value = oldVal & "," & newVal
      End If
    End If
   End If
   'setSecondValidation Target
   writeSeparatedString Target
End If

exitHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
Sub writeSeparatedString(rng As Range)
  Dim rngV2 As Range, arr As Variant, arrFin As Variant, El As Variant, k As Long

  arr = Split(rng.value, ",")
  ReDim arrFin((UBound(arr) + 1) * 3 - 1)
  
  For Each El In arr
    arrFin(k) = El & 1: k = k + 1
    arrFin(k) = El & 2: k = k + 1
    arrFin(k) = El & 3: k = k + 1
  Next
  Set rngV2 = rng.Offset(, -1)
  With rngV2
    .value = Join(arrFin, ", ")
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    .Select
  End With
End Sub
```

3. Try changing the cell "G1" value, using its drop-down list. **In its left side cell ("F1") the string separated by comma will appear**.

Please, test it and send some feedback...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220386/discussion-on-answer-by-faneduru-multiselect-dropdown-with-dependent-listbox).

Comment: Hello sir , I am not getting the solution for this code to make the cell F1 items unique means remove the duplicate one . You have made this code so you can modify it  and make changes in just few minutes.

Comment: This is the last modifications I am asking to make it.I am not getting the solution to remove the duplicates.